# Jquery: extend an object to modify a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to extend an object, and I want to modify a method of the first, not to override it. I don't think this is clear so here is an example:

```
var object1 = {
    whatever : function(){
        console.log('first object method');
    }
}

var object2 = {
    whatever : function(){
        console.log('second object method');
    }
}

var object = $.extend(true, object1, object2);

object.whatever();
```

This example will output `second object method`, but what I want is that it ouput `first object method` and `second object method`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's what the example is showing: when you define two method with the same name in the two object, the first is not triggered. I want something like `parent::whatever()` in PHP

Comment: Although JS has no in-built way of calling a superclass, you can do it using a technique described [here](http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/javascript/inheritance/inheritance10.htm).

Comment: No, `extends` doesn't "extends" functions, this is not what it was designed to do.

Comment: `$.extend` doesn't work that way.  It just replaces properties when there are duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript uses **prototypal inheritance**, so you can make object2 inherit object1's properties and methods by doing

```
object2.prototype=object1;
```

this means that object2 will inherit all the properties and methods of object1, and any overwritten methods can be accessed at `object2.prototype.method()`

so `parent::whatever();` is equivalent to `this.prototype.whatever();` when calling from the scope of object2.

---

```
var object1 = {
    whatever : function(){
        console.log('first object method');
    }
}

var object2 = {
    whatever : function(){
        console.log('second object method');
        this.prototype.whatever(); // Equivalent to parent::whatever(); 
    }
}

object2.prototype=object1; // Makes object2 inherit object1's properties and methods

object2.whatever(); // "second object method" "first object method"
```

Comment: Where do I have to add `object2.prototype=object1;`? In the second object or after?

Comment: Not as simple as I would like because in the app I am working on the first object will be extended several times, but it works, thanks!

Comment: If you need to extend it several times, use a prototype chain. So object2.prototype=object1; object3.prototype=object2; Object 3 will inherit first from object2, then from object1.